# Howto setup SMTP server without incoming mailserver?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, email

I'm trying to setup my private mailserver as SMTP server in Android 4.4. Every app I tried so far, Built-in Google app, Built-in Mail app and even K-9 mail which was mentioned many times on this forum, all require me to setup an incoming mailserver first. I tried the trick to provide wrong authentication info, but that doesn't work because each of the apps verifies it before proceeding. I'm not interested in having incoming mail on my phone because I've other ways to read the mail. Is it possible to setup the SMTP server without setting up an incoming mailserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things have changed. Currently it is possible to setup a SMTP server without having an incoming mailserver. K-9 mail still asks for an incoming mailserver and complains about the password which I've set wrong but doesn't insist on a correction.